# How stop a java function from another function?

Tags: java

I perform a function at all hours. This function performs a check of the last update to the database. When the last update of the database is larger than a specified time an email is sent to warn that there was no change in the database. 
What I want is that when you run a function for sending mail stop another function that I have to run every hour too.

Is it possible to do this?

Thank you.

```
public void check() {
    try {
        String sql="SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF((select curtime()), (SELECT MAX(hour_saveDB) FROM saves where date_saveDB like curdate())))";

        pst=(PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        while( rs.next() ) {
            int val =  ((Number) rs.getObject(1)).intValue();
            if( check != val ) {
                check=val;
                if( val > 7200 ) {
                    SendEmail();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume if that function is called every hour, it must be timer thread. Call interupt on that thread.

Comment: if val was a global variable, you could read the same in the other method.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Exactly the function has a timer. 
How can I do to stop this timer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep  reference of your timer and use  timer.cancel(); timer.purge(); to stop your timer.

Answer (score 1):

If the two function are linked and should both fired each hour, then group them in one schedduled function that calls the check() method returning a boolean.

```
function doTheJobEachHour {
if ( !check() ) {
    doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a shared variable between the two functions.

Then you can use it as

```
while(rs.next() && isEnabled){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. And then how can I stop the another function?